# using guice with servlet-api 3.1

Tags: jsp, tomcat, guice

I'm trying Guice 3.0 in my test web project. I've registered GuiceFilter and GuiceServletContextListener in web.xml. Than I've created and registered a servlet within ServletModule:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets() {
                serve("/enter").with(Dispatcher.class);
            }
        });
        bind(Logger.class).toInstance(Logger.getLogger("myLogger"));
    }
}
```

Dispather is called as expected, but when it forwards to JSP page I get an error:

request.getRequestDispatcher("/persons.jsp").forward(request, response);

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [56] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\user\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\web1\org\apache\jsp\persons_jsp.java]
The method getDispatcherType() is undefined for the type HttpServletRequest

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    servlets.Dispatcher.showPersons(Dispatcher.java:81)
    servlets.Dispatcher.process(Dispatcher.java:50)
    servlets.Dispatcher.doGet(Dispatcher.java:86)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
```

I believe this is due to incapability of servlet-api 3.1 used by Tomcat 8.0 and servlet-api 2.5 used by guice.

Is there any solution to this problem without downgrading my app server to servlet-api 2.5?

Tomcat's docs say that latest version that used 2.5 was Tomcat 6.

**Update:**
As it turns out servlet-api is declared in guice-servlet as "provided" dependency. All I had to do is declare my dependencies properly to omit this lib. My current configuration using ivy:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="mymodule"/>
    <dependencies defaultconfmapping="*->default">
        <dependency org="com.google.inject" name="guice" rev="3.0"/>
        <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="4.3.8.Final"/>
        <dependency org="com.google.inject.extensions" name="guice-servlet" rev="3.0"/>     
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```